# how does the mount system call works?

Tags: filesystems, mount

I am a newbie to linux, I want to understand the internal working of mount command. Can any one guide me to any good document or a book that explains the working. I would be very glad if anyone can even tell me any good book to understand the working of filesystem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a suspicion that some aspects of it are out of date, but [this document](http://tldp.org/LDP/khg/HyperNews/get/fs/vfstour.html) introduces the internals of some key parts of the VFS system which it sounds like you're interested in. There's also [documentation about VFS registration and mounting](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.35/Documentation/filesystems/vfs.txt) in the kernel tree too.

Comment: hey awoodland, that was helpful.. Thanks